# GroupBox Border not visible on Server 2016 when using the background color Gainsboro

Tags: c#, winforms, groupbox, windows-server-2016

We use the standard `GroupBox` and the `Flat`-Style. The form backgroundcolor is `Gainsboro`.

On my Windows 7 development machine it looks like this:

[image: Win7Example]

However, when running the app in a Windows Server 2016 Machine, it looks like this:

[image: Windows Server 2016]

The borders are gone (not visible).

It appears to has something to do with the Background Color, but we're not sure how to fix it. When using a light blue Color, this happens on Server 2016:

[image: othercolor]

Do you guys have any clue, why we can't see the white border with the BG-Color `Gainsboro`? It doesn't make any sense....

Comment: Are you logged on locally or via RDP?

Comment: I am local and using virtual box

Answer (score 1):

I dont have server 2016 to test it, but maybe overriding the `Paint` event of the borderColor will solve this problem, here is a custom `GroupBox` control, you can change `borderColor` Color inside the constructor.

```
namespace WindowsFormsApplication5
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            CustomGroupBox gb = new CustomGroupBox();
            gb.Location = new Point(5, 5);
            gb.Size = new Size(200, 100);
            this.Controls.Add(gb);
        }
    }


    public class CustomGroupBox : GroupBox
    {
        private Color borderColor;

        public Color BorderColor
        {
            get { return this.borderColor; }
            set { this.borderColor = value; }
        }

        public CustomGroupBox()
        {
            this.borderColor = Color.Red;
        }

        protected override void OnPaint(PaintEventArgs e)
        {
            Size tSize = TextRenderer.MeasureText(this.Text, this.Font);

            Rectangle borderRect = e.ClipRectangle;
            borderRect.Y += tSize.Height / 2;
            borderRect.Height -= tSize.Height / 2;
            ControlPaint.DrawBorder(e.Graphics, borderRect, this.borderColor, ButtonBorderStyle.Solid);

            Rectangle textRect = e.ClipRectangle;
            textRect.X += 6;
            textRect.Width = tSize.Width;
            textRect.Height = tSize.Height;
            e.Graphics.FillRectangle(new SolidBrush(this.BackColor), textRect);
            e.Graphics.DrawString(this.Text, this.Font, new SolidBrush(this.ForeColor), textRect);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I tried something similar, but it didn't look 100 % the same like before. But I will let you know on monday, if this works better. :)